# linux kernel space and user space communication with high efficiency

Tags: performance, kernel, communication

About the title,the kernel need to transfer some data(less than 1KB) to the user space,and the user space would also transfer some data(less than 1KB) after received the data from the kernel.I want to know some solutions with hign efficiency.NOW,I have handled the problem with netlink（bidirection communication）. AND,I want to use the signal(kernel to user) and system call in order to handle the problem more efficiently. Unfortunately,the real-time signal can only carry 4B data,it is so small.Are there some better ways so thant we can handle the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project, evevtually I choosed netlink for communication(transfer command) and mmap for sending data.There are some ways for communication between linux kernel and user's space.Click [here](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html).The best way was netlink for my project.The signal was bad, because it could only send `4B` data every time!

Answer (score 0):

Is shared memory an option for you?

Comment: I have used the shared memory to write and read data.   But I had no good ways to achieve the communication(kernel and user space)!   Thanks!

Comment: Ok so you are looking for a method by which user space application know that there is data available in kernel space and vice versa. For user space app to efficiently wait for data availability in kernel space, you could use an IOCTL call with a wait queue to put the process to sleep when data is not available. And for the kernel you could just use an IOCTL call which tells the kernel that data was just written to the buffer.

Comment: Thank you for your advise!  But I need a bidirection commution.Now,maybe netlink is the only way to meet my need.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on bidirectional communication? Netlink will have a lot of overhead compared to shared memory. Any reason why you feel Nelink will serve the purpose better than shared memory.

Comment: shared memory is best,but when you put data in shared memory(such as kernel put data),user space did not know the kernel have put the data. So we need to use netlink for notify.Now my project is using netlink for notify and shared memory for data transportation. Can you know it well?